# Primes completely splitting in a ring of integers which is a PID

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{6}]$.

1) Prove that $\mathscr{O}_K$ is a PID.

2) Let p be an odd prime, $p\neq 3$. Prove that there are integers $a,b$ such that $a^2-6b^2=\pm p$ if and only if $p=1,5,19,23\pmod{24}$.

**Solution**: $K$ is a real quadratic field, with $\operatorname{disc}(\mathscr{O}_K)=24$, hence every class in the class group can be represented by an ideal whose norm is lower than $\frac{2!}{2^2}\sqrt{24}=2,44...$. Since $N(2-\sqrt{6})=-2$, the prime factorizing $2\mathscr{O}_K$ is principal, therefore $\mathscr{O}_K$ is a PID.

The condition: "there exists $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^2-6b^2=\pm p$" is equivalent to "there exists $\alpha\in\mathscr{O}_K$ with $N(\alpha)=\pm p$" $\textbf{and this for a PID happens if and only if $p$ splits totally in $\mathscr{O}_K$}$.

Could someone explain me why the bold part is true?

Comment: You can also see my comment on user8628's answer, for an alternative way to look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p$ splits (or ramifies) iff there is an ideal $I$ such that $N(I)=p$; and since $I=(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$ (PID), it's iff $p=\pm N(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$.

Comment: You could also note that if $p$ is not inert, then necessarily $p\mathcal{O}_K=\mathfrak{P}\overline{\mathfrak{P}}$ where the overline denotes the Galois conjugate. From this and principalness it's fairly straightforward, and the reverse implication is similar.